# Load a public website and execute a script

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, web

I have my own website and when i press a button i want to load a website not owned by me ( i.e Google.com ). When this page loads i want to execute a script.

For example, click the button on my site, load google.com and preload the search bar with a value from the script file passed from my website.

I can do this if i open the developer console when i visit google.com and type the command in, however, i want to automate this so instead of loading he console myself, my script will manipulate the value of a DOM element of this new page.

I just don't know how to load a new website and give it a script to run.

Is this possible ? can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Comment: In general, no. At least, not from your own client-side code. The other page will be protected by the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). The other site has some options to offer exceptions, but that's not in your control. – However, depending on your needs, there are browser automation tools that are [often used for testing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/11785/how-does-one-get-started-with-web-test-automation-using-selenium).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, in fact, it's the basis of what many developers use during automated browser testing.

Take a look at Selenium - the below code for Java uses Selenium to do exactly what you've asked. Alternatively, something like Chrome Headless https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome or

PhantomJS http://phantomjs.org/quick-start.html will do the job.

```
package mypackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.By; 

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement; 
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class myclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\selenium-java-2.35.0\\chromedriver_win32_2.2\\chromedriver.exe");

         WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
         driver.get("http://www.google.com"); 
         WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
         element.sendKeys("Whatever");
         element.submit();

         driver.close();
    }



}
```

Comment: This is fine for webscraping or automated testing, but would not be suitable for the use case they appear to be describing, where they want to modify a 3rd party site within their own website.

Comment: Agreed @DanielBeck but for the purposes of providing a potential solution to an underlying problem, I've read between the lines i.e. "i want to automate this" IMO the likelihood is OP is familar with Javascript to a point and is trying to use it to perform some form of scraping or automation as the question doesn't seem that likely within a typical website.

Comment: "doesn't seem that likely within a typical website"  I have to talk clients out of this sort of thing all the time ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯